# Using N-Tier Entity Framework, how can I access an entity that has been marked as deleted?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, state, n-tier-architecture

Note: My project is using N-Tier Entity Framework (https://ntieref.codeplex.com/), which is different than regular Entity Framework.

On the Client side, when I attempt to access an entity that has been marked as deleted, it does not show up in my foreach loop.

```
foreach (var entity in DataContext.EntitySet.Where(x => x.ChangeTracker.State == ObjectState.Deleted))
```

I can’t access an entity that is marked as deleted.

```
var entity = DataContext.EntitySet.Where(x => x.ChangeTracker.State == ObjectState.Deleted).FirstOrDefault();
```

@ChristofSenn  How do I access the entity marked as deleted when I’m in the Client, before saving changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entities marked as deleted are hidden and don't get returned when enumerating the entity set. 
To get all entities (i.e. including deleted) you can use the following method:

Interface:

```
IEntitySet<TEntity>.GetAllEntities();
```

Sample:

```
foreach (var entity in DataContext.EntitySet
                             .GetAllEntities()
                             .Where(x => x.ChangeTracker.State == ObjectState.Deleted))
```